# Initializing a struct array inside a struct

Tags: c

I've looked at other questions but I can't seem to find a clear answer for this. How do I declare a struct array inside of a struct? I attempted to do it in main() but I don't know if I'm doing it right and I keep getting this warning: "initialization makes integer from a pointer without cast"

```
#define MAXCARDS 20     

struct card {
    int priority;       
};

struct battleQ {
    struct card cards[MAXCARDS];
    int head;
    int tail;
    int size;
};

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct battleQ bq;
    bq.cards = {
                      malloc(MAXCARDS * sizeof (struct card)), //Trouble with this part
                      0,
                      0,
                      0
                };

        //...

    return 1;
}
```

Edit after suggestions: Okay now I'm having problems. I keep getting this error:

```
3 [main] TurnBasedSystem 47792 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to TurnBasedSystem.exe.stackdump
```

I had to change the code a bit and make everything pointers. I tested it and it gives me that error as soon as I try to assign one of its attributes like: bq->head = 0

The entire thing is just supposed to add a card to a queue. Revised code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXCARDS 20

struct card {
    int priority;       
};

// A queue defined by a circular array
struct battleQ {
    struct card *cards[MAXCARDS];
    int head;
    int tail;
    int size;
};

bool battleQEnqueue (struct battleQ *bq, struct card *c);
bool battleQisFull(struct battleQ *bq);

// Method for enqueuing a card to the queue
bool battleQEnqueue (struct battleQ *bq, struct card *c) {
    bool success = false;
    if (battleQisFull(&bq)) {
        printf("Error: Battle queue is full\n");
    } else {
        success = true;
        bq->cards[bq->tail] = c;
        bq->size = bq->size + 1;
        bq->tail = (bq->tail + 1) % MAXCARDS;
    }
    return success;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    struct battleQ *bq;
    memset(&bq, 0, sizeof(bq));  // Did I do this properly?
    bq->tail = 0;               // Gives error at this point
    bq->head = 0;               
    bq->size = 0;

    // This is where I create a card and add it to the queue but the main problem
    // is still the initialization above
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        struct card *c = malloc(sizeof(c));
        c->priority = i + 10;
        printf("%d,", c->priority);
        battleQEnqueue(&bq, &c);
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: by the way, the trouble is probably caused by malloc returning a void*

Answer (score 3):

`bq.cards` is array of structs, you don't have to `malloc` it. 
You can initialize the entire array as:

```
memset(bq.cards, 0, sizeof(bq.cards));
```

If you want to initialize `bq` do

```
    memset(&bq, 0, sizeof(bq));
```

Comment: This should be: `memset(&bq, 0, sizeof bq)` in OPs case. (without all the `bq.cards = { ... }`.

Comment: @Lekensteyn, I'm not sure OP wants to initiazlise `bd` or `bq.cards` from the lvalue of statement it looks like `bq.cards`.

Comment: @Rohan Looks like `bq` to me since he sets the other members to `0` as well.

Comment: @Ron, As `bq` is pointer now, you have to allocate memory `bq=malloc(sizeof(*bq))` and `memset(bq, 0, sizeof(*bq))` or rather use `calloc()`.

Comment: @Rohan Thanks that works. But when I use the same thing to intialize cards[], it gives me that same error. I did: bq->cards = malloc(sizeof(*(bq->cards))); It says incompatible types when assigning struct card*[20] from type *void.

Comment: @Rohan Oh nvm I fixed it. I put bq->cards[i] = malloc(sizeof(*(bq->cards[i]))); and
  memset(bq->cards[i], 0, sizeof(*(bq->cards[i]))); into a for loop and it seemed to initialize everything fine. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You might like to initialise the whole structure this way:

```
...

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  struct battleQ bq =
  {
    {
      { 0 } /* int priority; */
    } /* (initialising the first element/member initialises all element/member) */
  }; 

  //...

  return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The initialization is in the declaration

```
struct battleQ bq = {
              {{0}, {0},... // 20 times
              },
                  0,
                  0,
                  0
            };
```

It might be better to have cards as the last element, then you can use a trick called the chumminess of C. http://c-faq.com/struct/structhack.html, where you can have a variable sized battleQ.

I may be wrong on this but what I've found on most compilers is that if you set the first element to zero, everything else will be zero.  I remember reading something in the standard about it but I can't remember were or whether it was C or C++.

```
struct battleQ bq = {{{0}}};
```

Comment: You don't need to specify an initializer for each array element if they all shall be 0, `struct battleQ bq = { {{0}}, 0, 0, 0 };` is enough. You don't even need that much, `struct battleQ bq = {0};` does the same. And instead of the struct hack one should use the standard way, a flexible array member.

Comment: Yes, I realized that after I wrote it and was going to correct it but I was asked to do something else by a higher authority.  Ha ha.  Never mind.